# Fancybox and LostGrid are giving me a hard time

Tags: html, css, fancybox, gallery

I need to put a gallery on my website that shows only the first picture of every category.
I'm also using FlexGrid as my layout has three columns.

I have a foreach loop which creates an `<a>` tag for every image, in order to have access to all the pictures opening the gallery.
What I did then is to hide all the `<a>`for image no. 2, 3, 4, etc.

The problem now is that LostGrid seems to still remember that I have all those `<a>` tag, even if I made them `display: none`, and the layout goes crazy.

I keep thinking about it but I really can't figure out what a solution could be.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

[What I'd like (right solution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnU5x.jpg)

[What I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2hJZ.jpg)

Here's the essential parts of my code (HTML/PHP [Kirby] + CSS [Stylus]):
Of course it won't work if you run it.

```css
.gallery
  display block
  margin-top 50px
  a
    display block
    lost-column 1/3 3 30px
    position relative
    padding-bottom 17.25%
    margin-bottom 30px
    > div
      position absolute
      top 0
      right 0
      bottom 0
      left 0
      background-size cover
      background-position center
    &.hidden
      display none
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
      <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
          <?php foreach($category->object()->toStructure() as $object): ?>
              <?php if($object->gallery()->isNotEmpty()): ?>
                  <?php $i = 0 ?>
                  <?php foreach($object->gallery()->toFiles() as $image): ?>
                      <a <?php e(!$i != 1, 'class="hidden"') ?> href="<?php echo $image->url() ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $image->caption()->html() ?>">
                          <div class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image->url() ?>')"></div>
                      </a>
                      <?php $i++ ?>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
              <?php endif ?>
          <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should provide us with the code you're working for an easier understanding of your problem

Comment: Hi Sorix, I added my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions, the simplest one probably would be to move additional links outside the main area, you can place them anywhere, since they are hidden anyway.

Comment: Anywhere else outside `<div class="gallery">`?

Comment: I actually thought "how can I put it outside my foreach? But I actually can, eventually, duplicate my foreach and then hide it all.

Comment: On second thought you know what? I don't really think this would work (I'll try anyway) because I wouldn't have the correct pictures order. :/

Comment: The order would be the same. btw, do you really need that LostGrid (I do not know what it is), maybe you would just be fine with plain flexbox, for example, https://css-tricks.com/adaptive-photo-layout-with-flexbox/ - but you can google for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I got it and, obviously, it was easier than I thought. Better late than never.

I had to put everything in a new container div, in order to give the size directly to `.gallery` and not the `a` tag inside of it.

I post the new code to show you what I mean.

```css
.referencesGallery
  display block
  margin-top 50px

  .gallery
    lost-column 1/3 3 30px
    position relative
    padding-bottom 17.25%
    margin-bottom 30px
    background-color lightpink
    a
      display block
      position absolute
      top 0
      right 0
      bottom 0
      left 0
      background-color lightblue
      > div
        position absolute
        top 0
        right 0
        bottom 0
        left 0
        background-size cover
        background-position center
      &.hidden
        display none
```

```html
<div class="referencesGallery">

    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <?php foreach($category->object()->toStructure() as $object): ?>
            <?php if($object->gallery()->isNotEmpty()): ?>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <?php $i = 0 ?>
                    <?php foreach($object->gallery()->toFiles() as $image): ?>
                        <a <?php e(!$i != 1, 'class="hidden"') ?> href="<?php echo $image->url() ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $image->caption()->html() ?>">
                            <div class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image->url() ?>')"></div>
                        </a>
                        <?php $i++ ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>
```

Thank you very much for your time!!
Sara